# add numbers in flutter by using provider

Tags: flutter-provider, textformfield, texteditingcontroller

I want to make a simple project to  sum  two numbers in flutter by using  provider with textformfield

I don't want to use setState . i want to Something like a simple calculator Such as entering a group of numbers and then adding them by elevatedButton or textButton